# SQL Lite - SUM returns null instead of the 0 (zero) value

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have this SQL query:

```
var sqlQuery =
  "SELECT '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_FROM+"' as DATE_FROM, "+
  " '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_TO+"' as DATE_TO, "+
  " COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT, "+
  " SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = '"+CALL_RESULT_STATE_APPT+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '"+APPT_CNT+"', "+
  " SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = '"+CALL_RESULT_STATE_CONV_NO_APPT+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '"+CONVERS_CNT+"' , "+
  " SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = '"+CALL_RESULT_STATE_CANNOT_REACH+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '"+CANNOT_REACH_CNT+"' "+
  " FROM "+DIALED_CALLS_TABLE+" dc "+
  " WHERE  dc.date BETWEEN '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_FROM+"' AND '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_TO+"';";
```

Problem is that if the sum of the values is zero result is containing value null.
I thought that i can solve it using `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`  but it is not working.

How can i solve it please to get result with zeros instead of the null?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just asking but.. How are you processing the query? Just wondering if it is safe enough to create a query in javascript that can easily be manipulated by the client resulting, therefore, in a possible easy-to-do injection.

Comment: Is it the Cordova mobile app.

Comment: Oh, never heard about that. Anyway, maybe add that in the description, someone can surely help you with that knowing that you're using such a framework, it usually isn't safe to create sql queries through javascript itself.

Answer (score 6):

SUM returns NULL when it does not get any value to begin with, i.e., when your WHERE clause does not match any rows.

If you can live with the result being a floating-point number, replace SUM with [TOTAL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc).
Otherwise, you can put an IFNULL around the entire sum:

```
SELECT ... IFNULL(SUM(CASE ... END), 0) FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think if some of your initiall values are null even the case/else won't work (null neither equals nor not-equals anything). Try putting some default, blank type value for nulls using IFNULL.

```
...
  " SUM(CASE WHEN IFNULL(dc.call_result,some_default_value) = '"+CALL_RESULT_STATE_APPT+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '"+APPT_CNT+"', "+
...
```

Comment: This is wrong; NULLs in the WHEN clause are interpreted as false.